# SSL and green color https

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have been looking everywhere but still confused with the "green color" https. Just the https and not the name as shown in websites like paypal.

I found this website selling for $20 USD per year: http://www.bigrock.in/digital-ssl-certificate/ and i'm wondering if this is enough to get my URL change to "https" and in "green" color from the ordinary http://

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

depends on browser but some of these use https as there reason for green other use standards. it just depends but is most browsers if all the content is https you will get the green label

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about Extended Validation (EV) certificate. The difference between normal SSL certificate and EV certificate is in the validation process that the requester must complete before CA issues the certificate. There are other minor differences like more information in Subject of EV certificate but the validation process is the main reason why it is considered a stronger certificate.

There are CAs that issue normal SSL certificates for free like [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/). The catch is that revocation is not free and if you loose private key and want to revoke the SSL certificate then you need to pay.

Other initiative that starter recently is [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). It should be totally free but they are not operational yet (Q4/2015).

Comment: I bought the simple SSL for $20 and it works. I wasn't talking about EV Certificate.